React Native NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance
I'm trying to integrate react native app to existing IOS app. But i get the error below.
Error Log :
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTCxxBridge devSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d3317c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18b500f20 0x183386018 0x18b60a480 0x18b49dfb4 0x18b49d8d0 0x11232eaec 0x11232be48 0x111578b98 0x11157a7bc 0x11158ed18 0x11158f4d8 0x1e83578f8 0x1e83540cc)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
react: 18.3.1
react-native : 0.74.2
Sample codes from : https://github.com/duytq94/demo-integrate-react-native/tree/master
RNViewManager.swift
import Foundation
import React

class RNViewManager: NSObject {
    var bridge: RCTBridge?
    
    static let sharedInstance = RNViewManager()
    
    func createBridgeIfNeeded() -> RCTBridge {
        if bridge == nil {
            bridge = RCTBridge.init(delegate: self, launchOptions: nil)
        }
        return bridge!
    }
    
    func viewForModule(_ moduleName: String, initialProperties: [String : Any]?) -> RCTRootView {
        let viewBridge = createBridgeIfNeeded()
        let rootView: RCTRootView = RCTRootView(
            bridge: viewBridge,
            moduleName: moduleName,
            initialProperties: initialProperties)
        return rootView
    }
}

extension RNViewManager: RCTBridgeDelegate {
    func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! {
        #if DEBUG
            return URL(string: "http://192.168.1.25:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios")
        #else
            return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")
        #endif
    }
}

Sample Button Click Code :
let rootView = RNViewManager.sharedInstance.viewForModule(
                   "MyReactNativeApp",
                   initialProperties: ["message_from_native": "messageFromNative"])
               
let reactNativeVC = UIViewController()
reactNativeVC.view = rootView
reactNativeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(reactNativeVC, animated: true)


Please check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23824#issue-418866933 "Update at last"

Sorry not helped :(

Try to add flag to your library file https://stackoverflow.com/a/32856812/833395

On Xcode, you have to add $(inherited) parameter to the "Other Linker Flags"
which is under App -> Build Settings -> Linking - General

